# Clarifying the claim of "full Ubuntu desktop OS" support on the Ubuntu Edge

Tags: phone, ubuntu-edge

Can anyone clarify what Canonical means when creating a "full Ubuntu desktop OS" on the proposed Ubuntu edge?

My definition of a "full Ubuntu desktop OS" is if a software package can be complied for Ubuntu 13.04 the Ubuntu 13.04 OS on the Ubuntu Edge will *attempt* to run said software if in desktop mode.

I say *attempt* as any desktop can fail to run correctly compiled software but they will all *attempt* to run the software.

Does my definition of a "full Ubuntu desktop OS" match Canonical's definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the Edge is designed to work with Ubuntu Touch and Android as a handset, and when connected to a monitor using HDMI *then* you see the Ubuntu desktop experience, that is, the phone OS becomes the full Ubuntu Desktop OS on the monitor.

I can't speak for Canonical, that however is my understanding.

Comment: Agreed, these are indeed the details we know for sure about the about the Ubuntu Edge desktop mode. What I also know is the status quo for mobile devices is to not run a full desktop operating system on a mobile device. Does Canonical plan to break this status quo with the Ubuntu Edge?

Comment: again that is my understanding. I believe it's supposed to be running a dual core 2.4Ghz processor with 4Gb Ram and 128Gb HDD, which is ample to run a full OS

Comment: And if Canonical delivers on fully (or even mostly) supporting a desktop OS on the Edge that is built to use standard libraries and software, I will be extremely happy. But then again this worry is a little premature. Canonical likely doesn't have any details worked out in this regard and honesty, lets hope the crowd funding successes. I really want a new phone-desktop to play with in 2014.